# How can we Clear Contents of DynamicMenu constructed within Ribbon on ribbon.invalidate()

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, ribbon, ribbon-control, ribbonx

I am creating Outlook ribbon which has couple of dynamic menus in it, I am invalidating ribbon on click of dynamic menu buttons. Problem I am facing is when I say `ribbon.invalidate()` contents of dynamic menu are not cleared and holds contents which were added previously.

How can I clear the dynamic menu and force to rebuild it ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your ribbon XML markup?

In essence you needed to implement the `getContent` callback in the code for the dynamic menu control where you return an appropriate dynamic ribbon XML markup.

You can read more about the Fluent UI in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Also you can read about dynamic customizations in the Fluent UI and find the sample code:

- [Adding Custom Dynamic Menus to the Office Fluent User Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462634%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548010(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548011(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I have implemented getContent callback in code which builds the dynamic menu. getContent is called again after i invalidate, dynamic menu is built again with new values but ribbon button refer to the same old dynamic menu again rather than pointing to newly build dynamicMenu

Comment: can someone help me here?